# Setting styles of programmatically added Views

Tags: android, android-styles, programmatically-created

In my code, I add input elements like radioButtons, checkboxes etc to my Layout programmatically.
The problem is, that the style of those elements is not the default style that you would get, when you would add let's say a radioButton via xml. (It looks really white and almost see-through on a white application background. A bit like it is transparent)
Also, the EditText elements I'm adding have the same style and if you type something in them, the text is too big and overlaps the text line a bit.
So I guess it all comes down to somehow giving those elements their default style, like they look when defined via xml.

A sample of my code looks like this:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(mContext);
    radioGroup.setLayoutParams(fullWidthWrapHeight);

    for (int i = 0; i < arg0.getOptions().size(); i++){
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mContext, null);
        radioButton.setPadding(padding16dp , padding8dp, padding16dp, padding8dp);
        radioButton.setText(arg0.getOptions().get(i).getText());
        radioButton.setLayoutParams(wrapBoth);
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        radioButton.setTextAppearance(mContext, R.style.Default_Text);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
```

My target API lvl is 21 (Lollipop)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can pass a style defined inside `styles.xml` as an argument of a `View` constructor. So considering your example, you would have to call:

```
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mContext, null, R.attr.radioButtonStyle);
```

then add custom attribute inside `attrs.xml`

```
<attr name="radioButtonStyle" format="reference" />
```

and inside your application theme in `styles.xml` add

```
<item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/YourRadioButtonStyle</item>
```

`YourRadioButtonStyle` is custom radio button style defined in `styles.xml`

Comment: Is it also somehow possible to pass the default radioButton style, or do I have to create a new style that has the default style as parent?

Comment: you have to define `YourRadioButtonStyle` that has `@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton` as a parent and sets some fields in the way you want

Comment: to pass the default radioButton style you should be able to use `com.android.internal.R.attr.radioButtonStyle` instead of `R.attr.radioButtonStyle`

Comment: If I do it, the text overlaps the checkbox image... some idea why this ocurs?

Comment: maybe it's somehow related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16739017/1993204)

Comment: @Cuddl3s is there a reason why you didn't accept the answer?

Comment: @BartekLipinski you mean other than me forgetting about it cause I posted it quite some time ago? :) Fixed!

Comment: @Cuddl3s treat my comment as a gentle reminder then :D thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for me, it has been successfully solved just by that way:

**Activity.java**

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

...

```
    { 
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_butt, null);
        rb.setText(this_currency_option);
        rb.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        rb.setId(100 + i);
        radioGroup.addView(rb);
    }
```

**radio_butt.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/MyRadioButtonStyle"/>
```

**slyles.xml**

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAlfaWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```