# Radio Button style programmatically

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I would to create a number of radio button dinamically in a fragment, I only have problem with style. If I put radiobutton code in the xml file, default style is applied correctly, but when I create radiobutton through a function I see different style!

XML

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animationCache="false">

            <RadioButton
                android:text="RadioButton 1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="RadioButton 2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />


</RadioGroup>
```

RESULT

[image]

JAVA CODE

This code is put in onCreateView in the fragment

```
public void addRadioButton(Context ctx,int num){

    RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) alertInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton  = new RadioButton(ctx);
        radioButton.setId(1+i);
        radioButton.setText("Radio " + radioButton.getId());
        radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

    }

}
```

RESULT

[image]

As you can see radio buttons have different style, someone could help me, if is possibile, to apply default style programmatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting styles of programmatically added Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046878/setting-styles-of-programmatically-added-views)

Answer (score 15):

you have to create style on drawable or style.xml, as your requirement.

**drawable/null_selector.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
         <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> 
  </selector>
```

Set each button to use it (and to center the text) like this (R.drawable.null_selector is selector XML):

Now, In your Activity, you must be implement such style.

```
  RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(ctx);
  radioButton.setText(Integer.toString(i));
  radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
  radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.null_selector);
```

I think, this will help you for implementing custom style in Radio Button.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks Dharma, I followed your suggestion, changing something, and I solved!

JAVA CODE

```
public void addRadioButton(Context ctx,int num){

    RadioGroup radioGroup= (RadioGroup) alertInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    RadioGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){

        RadioButton radioButton  = new RadioButton(ctx);
        radioButton.setId(1+i);
        radioButton.setText("Radio"+i);
        radioButton.setTextSize(16);
        radioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_button_selector);
        radioButton.setPadding(80,0,0,0);
        radioButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        radioButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);

    }

}
```

XML RADIO BUTTON SELECTOR with checked and unchecked button image

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/unchekedradiobutton" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkedradiobutton" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchekedradiobutton" /> <!-- default -->
```

Answer (score 6):

Use an Inflater instance to inflate a custom layout and easily get a custom Radiobutton

```
private RadioButton createCustomRadioButton(Context context){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radio_button,null);
    RadioButton radioButton  = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.radio_button);
    radioButton.setText("It Works!");

    ((ViewGroup)radioButton.getParent()).removeView(radioButton);
    return radioButton;
}
```

radio_buttom.xml

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_button"
    style="@style/radio"
    android:background="@drawable/style_line" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="radio">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:drawablePadding">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hintColor</item>
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/whiteColor</item>
</style>
```

by Ubirajara (México)

Answer (score 2):

Programmatically, I recommend setting a **ColorStateList** to each radio button in the loop like this:
`radioButton.setButtonTintList(getRadioButtonColors());`

Then

```
private ColorStateList getRadioButtonColors() {
        return new ColorStateList (
                new int[][] {
                        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked
                        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled} // unchecked
                },
                new int[] {
                        Color.GREEN, // checked
                        Color.BLUE   // unchecked
                }
        );
    }
```

Where `android.R.attr.state_checked` defines the color for the checked button **(green)** and `android.R.attr.state_enabled` defines the color for unchecked buttons **(blue)**.

Personally I think this is a better solution because it's more concise than creating styles and other dependencies elsewhere in the codebase. Whenever possible use the most concise and efficient approach.